# Require js and backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm getting a backbone is undefined error when trying to apply require js to my code. I've read other articles on the site saying to use shim and it did not resolve the issue.

helper/util.js:

```
require.config({

waitSeconds: 10,
paths: {
    "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min",
    "underscore": "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min",
    "backbone": "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min"
},
shim: {
    jquery: {
        exports: "$"
    }, 
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore","jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    app: {
        deps: ["backbone"],
        exports: "App"
    }
}

});
require(["Scripts/jquery.flip.min.js"]);
require(["Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"]);
require(["Scripts/RatingProviders.js"]);
```

main.js:

```
require(["helper/util"], function(App) {
    //Models
     TestProvider = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            ID: '',
            Name: '',
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.ID= '';
            this.Name= '';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, the content of the helper/util.js file would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

My educated guess would be that you never actually `require` Backbone.

Try to require it like that:

```
require(["helper/util", "Backbone"], function(App) {
    //Models
     TestProvider = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            ID: '',
            Name: '',
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.ID= '';
            this.Name= '';
        }
    });
});
```

Shim config tells the loader what to do when Backbone is part of a module's requirement but isn't actually an AMD Module.

Answer (score 2):

All in all, your file doesn't make much sense. Here you are **defining** a class, so you should use the `define` function.

```
define(["helper/util"], function(App) {
```

You're not using the `App` var, so let's remove it:

```
define([], function() {
```

Now, we want to include Backbone (see Nirazul's answer for the **shim** explanation) to be sure that it's loaded. Also, Backbone will be a global var, so you're not required to declare it in the argument list:

```
define(['backbone'], function() {
```

Now, you have to return your new class:

```
return TestProvider = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

Also, for your jQuery plugin, you can also change some things. First, declare them in `require.config` (specify jQuery as a dependency in shim). Then, add them as dependencies to whatever class that requires them. That way, you're loading them asynchronously when they are actually needed.

Comment: I guess the intention was to provide an example to test the require-functionality. Of course, it could be otherwise...

Comment: @Nirazul you may be right, but such an example, in my opinion, shows little understanding of requirejs. So I'm just providing as much details as possible.